# While loop, python beginner

Tags: python

I am taking MIT python programming course online. Right now we are learning for and while.

[image]

This is the first problem set. When I run this program, it gives me an infinite loop instead of a single number of months as I intended.  Please see the attachment for assignment and error and below are my codes:

```
 `annual_salary=float(input("What is your starting annual salary?"))
 portion_saved=float(input("Enter the percentage of your annual 
 salary save, as a decimal"))
 total_cost=float(input("How much does your dream house cost?"))

 current_saving=0
 r=0.04
 portion_down_payment=0.25
 downpayment_amt=total_cost*portion_down_payment
 principal=annual_salary*(1+portion_saved)
 difference=downpayment_amt-current_saving
 
 month=0
 while difference>0:
     month+=1
     current_saving=principal*(1+r/12)**month
     print("Number of months:", month)`
```

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDwKY.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbb5R.jpg)

Comment: Could you please post the error you are getting? And more importantly which data are you entering to the input variables.

Comment: Please be more specific than "my code does not work". How should this code work and what does it currently do that doesn't meet your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

you haven't defined what the variable `year` is!

Comment: Well, you don't update what `difference` is! Your while loop needs to contain code to re-define what difference is with whatever updated values each iteration. Otherwise, `difference` will always be equal to the value you set it at initially. Just because you change `current_saving` , it doesn't automatically update `difference` ! The computer reads top to bottom and won't go back to update things even if they depend on variables that change subsequently (usually...).

Answer (score 1):

```
 annual_salary=float(input("What is your starting annual salary?"))
 portion_saved=float(input("Enter the percentage of your annual 
 salary save, as a decimal"))
 total_cost=float(input("How much does your dream house cost?"))

 current_saving=0
 r=0.04
 portion_down_payment=0.25
 downpayment_amt=total_cost*portion_down_payment
 principal=annual_salary*(1+portion_saved)
 difference=downpayment_amt-current_saving

 year = 0 #you omitted to define this variable

 while difference>0:
     year+=1
     current_saving=principal*(1+r/12)**year
     difference-=current_saving  #you also omitted to update difference
     print("Number of months:", year)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Even if I defined it, it still gave me an infinite loop. Please see my updated question.

Comment: it is because you don't modify difference inside yout while loop, i edited the answer, try now

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a while loop...
For example, you can do something like that:

```
months = total_cost / annual_salary

print("Number of months:", months)
```

And you can add the "r" variable into the equation as well.